# My Crystal Report is not showing the hole list

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Please help with my crystal report, because it doesn't show the hole list when i use parameter fields for a list. here is my class below

```
`Imports System.Windows.Forms.Application

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Public Class CrystalReportHelperClass

    Dim Sql As New SqlHelper

    Dim CR_ParamDisVals As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim CR_ParamVals As New ParameterValues

    Dim CR_ParamDef As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim CR_ParamDefs As ParameterFieldDefinitions

    Dim CRPTDoc As New ReportDocument
    Dim CRPTViewer As New CrystalReportViewer

    Public Sub New(ByRef CReport As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer)

        CRPTViewer = CReport
        CRPTDoc = CReport.ReportSource
    End Sub
    Public Sub CrystalObjectParam(ByVal CrystalReportObject As String, ByVal Message As String)

        CR_ParamDisVals.Value = Message
        CR_ParamDefs = CRPTDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        CR_ParamDef = CR_ParamDefs.Item(CrystalReportObject)

        CR_ParamVals = CR_ParamDef.CurrentValues

        CR_ParamVals.Clear()
        CR_ParamVals.Add(CR_ParamDisVals)

        CR_ParamDef.ApplyCurrentValues(CR_ParamVals)

    End Sub

    Public Function GetCrystalReport() As ReportDocument
        Return CRPTDoc
    End Function

End Class
`
```

then here is the form load

```
  Private Sub ReportEmployeeList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim RepDoc As New ReportDocument
    RepDoc = CRPT_Employee.ReportSource
    If Sql.HasConnection() = True Then

        Dim DT As DataTable = Sql.ExecuteDataTableSP("SelectWorking")
        For Each Data As DataRow In DT.Rows

            CRPT.CrystalObjectParam("ID", Data(1))

        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("System Database Cannot be Connected", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If

    CRPT_Employee.ReportSource = CRPT.GetCrystalReport
    CRPT_Employee.Refresh()

End Sub
```

then i have 1 parameter field in my crystal report, id -> discrete value 
what should i do? 
i already used other methods like this one

`Private Sub SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(ByVal myParameterFields As ParameterFields, ByVal myArrayList As ArrayList)
        Dim currentParameterValues As ParameterValues = New ParameterValues()
        For Each submittedValue As Object In myArrayList
            Dim myParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
            myParameterDiscreteValue.Value = submittedValue.ToString()
            currentParameterValues.Add(myParameterDiscreteValue)
        Next
        Dim myParameterField As ParameterField = myParameterFields(PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME)
        myParameterField.CurrentValues = currentParameterValues
    End Sub`

Comment: can you explain what do you want exactly...

Comment: when i load the form and look at the crystal report viewer it only show the last row of my database. its like the previous data are overlapped by last data of my database

Comment: i want to know if the parameter field in crystals report can be place with list of variables, like list of names. if yes it can, tell me who to or if it can't, why?

Comment: can you provide example please ??

Comment: i mean in just by using 1 field i could just the add an item until the last item, but it seem that the last item only appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your method as below if i understood what do you want>>>

```
 Dim DT As DataTable = Sql.ExecuteDataTableSP("SelectWorking")
    For Each Data As DataRow In DT.Rows

        CRPT.SetParameterValue("ID", Data(1))
```

Comment: still the last data appears and the rest none

Comment: @PhilChristianTapia you can do something like this: CRPT.SetParameterValue("ID",DT.columns(the desired column from data set))